# Bash cat files in a directory into one file inserting filename before content

Tags: bash, shell, cat

I have a directory of txt files to cat into another file. But I need to put a header before the content of each file. Specifically, I would like to do something like this:

```
---------------- <FILENAME> ----------------
content
---------------- <FILENAME2> ---------------
content
```

Actually I don't need all the "------------" before and after the filename, but it would be nice.

Thank you for your time ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`for f in *.txt; do echo "----------------<$f>----------------"; cat "$f"; done >> OUTPUT_FILE`

Comment: You could also do `> OUTPUT_FILE` to empty an existing file.

Comment: Could be simplified altogether as: `for f in *.txt; do echo "----------------<$f>----------------"; cat "$f"; done > OUTPUT_FILE` :)